# Instantiation of a vector of type with no operator=

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to make a vector of `DataEntry` objects, which have had their `operator=` disabled:

```
using Row = vector<DataEntry>;

class DataTable {
public:
    vector<Row> data;
};
```

This results in an error

```
in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<DataEntry, std::__1::allocator<DataEntry> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<DataEntry,
          std::__1::allocator<DataEntry> > > >::operator=' requested here
    class DataTable {
```

Is there a way to get around this and make the vector without accidentally using `operator=`?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to get around this and make the vector without accidentally using the operator=?

No, there isn't.

One of the requirements of `T` for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is:

> `T` must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible.

If you are able to use a compiler that supports C++14 or C++17, the requirements are a little less strict.

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container.  Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

Comment: After C++11, this is not so simple. [The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) so it doesn't *have* to be CopyAssignable. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From C++11 the requirements that are imposed on the elements [depend on the actual operations performed on the container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) so as long as you avoid any operations that could assign to an element you can use a `std::vector<DataEntry>`. I believe this includes any operations that resize the vector, as a resize could cause a re-allocation which requires the existing elements to be assigned to new elements.

Here is an example of using a `std::vector<DataEntry>` where `DataEntry` is non-copyable and non-assignable. I simply make sure the `std::vector` is initialized with the correct size:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class DataEntry {
public:
  int value;
  DataEntry() = default;
  DataEntry(const DataEntry&) = delete;
  DataEntry& operator=(const DataEntry&) = delete;  
};

using Row = std::vector<DataEntry>;

class DataTable {
public:
  std::vector<Row> data;
  DataTable(size_t rowCount, size_t columnCount) : data(rowCount) {
    for(auto& row : data) {
      row = Row{columnCount};
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  DataTable table(4, 3);
  table.data[2][1].value = 2;
  std::cout << table.data[3][2].value << "\n"; 
  std::cout << table.data[2][1].value << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/us7sMv4pwoZRvFp5).

What are your requirements for `DataEntry` to be non-assignable? Perhaps `DataEntry` could be [movable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)? That would give you more options.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `vector<DataEntry>` to `vector<DataEntry*>` etc, with all implications of it. That would allow you to create your vector and still have no assignment op on DataEntry and have it somehow "protected" from accidental assignements, however that of course would apply to `DataEntry` and not to `DataEntry*` used by the vector, so it will certainly not prevent you from accidentally doing `data[4] = nullptr`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Careful with this, because assigning one `vector<DataEntry*>` to another (such as in the compiler's generated `operator=` for `DataTable`) will copy the `DataEntry*` pointers as-is, and having multiple `DataTable` objects refer to the same `DataEntry` objects is probably not what you want.

Comment: @M.Dow: It may seem like it was a nice easy solution for you, but honestly this is probably _not_ what you want to do. Having a container of pointers just opens up more problems, many of them subtle. Why not make your data type assignable? In a world of move semantics this is almost always feasible. Exceptions are things like streams which you shouldn't be containing in the first place.

Comment: @M.Dow: if it worked like a charm, please now focus on the `with all implications of it` part. I really mean it. Remy is right in that playing with raw pointers can be tricky. I have no idea how experienced you are, but consider at least changing `vector<DataEntry*>` to i.e. `vector<unique_ptr<DataEntry>>` or shared_ptr to ensure proper item lifetime management.